# How can I use a value extracted from a dataframe to specify columns to subset in R?

Tags: r, subset

I have a dataframe that I want to subset inside a function so that only rows where both columns are either 1 or NA remain. For df:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,1,0,NA,0,1), 
                 b = c(0,1,0,1,0, NA),
                 c = c(0,0,0,0,0,0))
```

I want:

```
   a  b  c
2  1  1  0
4 NA  1  0
6  1 NA  0
```

The problem I'm having is I have many columns with names that change. So this works well:

```
subset(df, (is.na(a) | a == 1) & (is.na(b) | b == 1))
```

but when column names 'a' and 'b' become 'd' and 'f' during the operation of the function it breaks. Specifying by column index works more robustly:

```
subset(df, (is.na(df[,1]) | df[,1] == 1) & (is.na(df[,2]) | df[,2] == 1))
```

But is cumbersome, and if a previous processing step messes up and column 'c' ends up before 'a' or 'b' I end up subsetting by the wrong columns.

I also have another dataframe that specifies what the column names to subset by will be:

```
cro_df <- data.frame(pop = c('c1', 'c2'),
                     p1 = c('a', 'd'),
                     p2 = c('b', 'f'))
  pop p1 p2
1  c1  a  d
2  c2  b  f
```

I would like to be able to extract the column names from that dataframe to use in my subset function, e.g.:

```
col1 <- cro_df[cro_df[,'pop']=='c1', 'p1']
subset(df, is.na(col1) | col1 == 1)
```

This returns an empty dataframe. I have tried turning col1 into a symbol and a factor with no success:

```
subset(df, as.symbol(col1) == 1)
subset(df, sym(col1) == 1)
subset(df, as.factor(col1) == 1)
```

And they all return:

```
[1] a b c
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Is there a way I can specify my columns to subset using the second dataframe cro_df?

Comment: `but when 'a' and 'b' becomes 'd' and 'f' it breaks` doesn't make a lot of sense, renaming the columns `df2 <- setNames(df, c("d","f","c"))` produces the same results with `subset(df2, (is.na(d) | d == 1) & (is.na(f) | f == 1))`.

Comment: My bad, this is inside of a function, so the column names 'a' and 'b' can change to 'd' and 'f' without giving me a chance to change the code inside the 'subset' function. I'll edit for clarity

Comment: Are there values other than 0, 1, NA in the dataframe? You may change all NAs to a special number, e.g., 0.5, and then extract rows with sum = 1.5. It will be helpful if you can provide more columns.

Comment: Yes, right now there are 16 different column names that can be found in 22 combinations, and I may need to add more down the line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter` and `if_all` from the `dplyr` package.

Select in the manner you find best suited for your case the names of the columns you want to filter. In my case I just created a variable `cols` that contains `'a'` and `'b'`.

Then I check `all_of` the column names in `cols` and `filter` the rows `if_all` statements are `TRUE`:

```
library(dplyr) # packageVersion("dplyr") >= 1.1.0

cols <- c('a', 'b')
filter(df, if_all(all_of(cols), \(x) is.na(x) | x == 1))
#>    a  b c
#> 1  1  1 0
#> 2 NA  1 0
#> 3  1 NA 0
```

If you assign different column names to `cols` you can reuse the same code.

Comment: This ended up being very robust for my use case, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
  
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,1,0,NA,0,1), 
                 b = c(0,1,0,1,0, NA),
                 c = c(0,0,0,0,0,0))
```

Let’s add a second data frame with different column names.

```r
df2 <- data.frame(d = c(1,1,0,NA,0,1), 
                 f = c(0,1,0,1,0, NA),
                 c = c(0,0,0,0,0,0))
```

We can use `dplyr::if_all()` in `dplyr::filter()` to apply the filter.

```r
df |> 
  filter(if_all(c(a, b), \(x) is.na(x) | x == 1))
#>    a  b c
#> 1  1  1 0
#> 2 NA  1 0
#> 3  1 NA 0
```

Using that idea we now write a custom function to accomodate for changing
column names.

```r
custom_filter <- 
  function(data, v1, v2) {
    filter(data,
           if_all(c({{v1}}, {{v2}}), \(x) is.na(x) | x == 1))
  }
```

Here is how that can work.

```r
custom_filter(df, a, b)
#>    a  b c
#> 1  1  1 0
#> 2 NA  1 0
#> 3  1 NA 0
custom_filter(df2, d, f)
#>    d  f c
#> 1  1  1 0
#> 2 NA  1 0
#> 3  1 NA 0
```

Using your `cro_df` dataframe and by placing all dataframes in a `list()`
we can now programmatically (`purrr::map2()`) go through all of the
dataframes and apply the filter.

```r
cro_df <- data.frame(pop = c('c1', 'c2'),
                     p1 = c('a', 'd'),
                     p2 = c('b', 'f'))

cro_l <- 
  cro_df |> 
  split(1:nrow(cro_df))

data_l <- list(df, df2)

map2(data_l,
     cro_l,
     \(x, y) custom_filter(
       x, y$p1, y$p2
     ))
#> [[1]]
#>    a  b c
#> 1  1  1 0
#> 2 NA  1 0
#> 3  1 NA 0
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>    d  f c
#> 1  1  1 0
#> 2 NA  1 0
#> 3  1 NA 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is a good start?

```r
with(cro_df[cro_df$pop == "c1",],
  df[ (is.na(df[[p1]]) | df[[p1]] == 1) & (is.na(df[[p2]]) | df[[p2]] == 1), ]
)
#    a  b c
# 2  1  1 0
# 4 NA  1 0
# 6  1 NA 0
```

FYI, [`subset`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/subset.html) is intended for interactive use, its help page says

```
Warning:

     This is a convenience function intended for use interactively.
     For programming it is better to use the standard subsetting
     functions like [, and in particular the non-standard evaluation
     of argument ‘subset’ can have unanticipated consequences.
```

Comment: This worked great at first! Unfortunately some of my column names have '-' in them (and I can't change them because they are names used throughout multiple research groups), and I couldn't easily find a way to make this robust against names like that. I will keep playing with it though

Comment: How does that change things? I just renamed `"b"` to `"b-"` and adjusted `cro_df` accordingly, and I got no error. The use of `[[` is resilient to non-standard names like that. As long as `p1` and `p2` strings are found as column names in `df`, this should work.